# jQuery Masonry: margin 0 auto

Tags: css, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to use Masonry to create a two-column, centered content area. I want this area to be `500px` wide. Currently I've got the width of each column at `240px`, with the left column having a `10px` padding-right (just realized I need to have it be `20px` to fit the `500px` completely).

I can't get the container, the it's parent, or the individual columns to be centered, though. I've tried multiple different ways to get this to work (see: https://github.com/bnb/bnb.github.com/commits/master), but it seems that every time I make a change Masonry overrides it. Most recently, I tried using the `containerStyle` function, but that had (as far as I could tell) the same results as the regular CSS.

Does anybody have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Here's what I've got as the arguments right now for Masonry:

```
$tumblelog.masonry({
  isFitWidth: true,
  columnWidth: 240  
  containerStyle: { 
    width: 500px;   
    margin: 0 auto; 
  }
});
```

Comment: Please paste the code here - and not refer us to an external site that may lose relevance or context.

Comment: Updated the post with my JS. Do you need to see the different CSS styles I tried, too?

Comment: It's always good idea to attach working/broken example for example at http://jsfiddle.net/, in process of doing it you might find the answer  on your question by your self.